# elasticsearch parent/children aggregation performance

Tags: elasticsearch

I am just an elasticsearch newbie. According to the following elasticsearch document,

- [join datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html#_parent_join_and_performance)

  > The join field shouldn’t be used like joins in a relation database. In Elasticsearch the key to good performance is to de-normalize your data into documents. Each join field, **has_child** or **has_parent** query adds a significant tax to your query performance.
- [has_child query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-child-query.html)

  > Note that the **has_child** is a slow query compared to other queries in the query dsl due to the fact that it performs a join.
- [has_parent query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-parent-query.html)

  > Note that the **has_parent** is a slow query compared to other queries in the query dsl due to the fact that it performs a join.

I can understand these query types are slow and should be avoided. But what about [parent](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-parent-aggregation.html) and [children](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-children-aggregation.html) aggregations ? I can not find any document or performance test result which says these aggregations are slow or not so bad.

I have to test it though, can someone give me some advice ?

Answer (score 2):

Parent and Child Aggregations are definitely slower compared to other Aggregations. I have tested it in my applications and found it much slower than normal ones.

Comment: Thanks ! I have to test it too.